# How sequelize generate T-SQL query with sum, order and group?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I have this sequelize query, it gives a total taxable by article categories group.

```
const result = await models.Sale.findAll({
        raw: true,
        attributes: [
            [Sequelize.literal('SUM(Sales.totalTaxable)'), 'total'], 
            "Article.category"
        ],
        limit: 25,
        offset: 0,
        where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('YEAR', Sequelize.col('docDate')), year)
        include: [{ model: models.Article, attributes: [] }],
        group: ["Article.category"],
        order: [[models.Article, "category", "DESC"], [Sequelize.literal("total"), "DESC"],],
    })
```

and the output is that query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Sales.totalTaxable) AS [total], [Article].[category] 
FROM 
    [Sales] AS [Sales] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Articles] AS [Article] ON [Sales].[ArticleId] = [Article].[id] 
                            AND ([Article].[deletedAt] IS NULL) 
WHERE 
    (YEAR([docDate]) = N'2021'
GROUP BY 
    [Article].[category] 
ORDER BY 
    [Sales].[id] 
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY;
```

It does not work because of `ORDER BY [Sales].[id]` but it's automatically added by sequelize and it's clearly unwanted.
(manually testing without it works)

I'm using sequelize v6.6.5, dialect: mssql (tedious)

Is this a sequelize bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you try `await models.Sale.sum` ?

Comment: @Anatoly yes but it doesn't work with include option and literals

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately, you're right. My bad.

Comment: So, `order: [[models.Article, "category", "DESC"], [Sequelize.literal("total"), "DESC"],],` just doesn't work?

Comment: @Anatoly it doesn't work. I fell back to sequelize.query() method with a raw query.